# Not able to run conf.js with Protractor Azure Pipeline

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, azure-devops, protractor

This is my `YAML` and I'm able to install `npm`, update and start the `webdriver-manager`, but I don't know how to run my `conf.js` file

This is my `YAML`:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/9whzK.png][1]

And this is the run:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsIbQ.png][2]

I'm new in Azure DevOps so please just guide me through how I'm supposed to run the test and the dependencies that I'm using on my script because It runs without a problem locally.

Answer (score 0):

> Not able to run conf.js with Protractor Azure Pipeline

To run the test with Protractor, you can use the command line task with node tool to run the test, like:

```
- task: CmdLine@1
  displayName: 'Run node'
  inputs:
    filename: node
    arguments: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Conf\Protractor.conf.js'
  enabled: false
```

There is a great document about [how to use Protractor End to End Tests Configure on CI/CD TFS/VSTS (Azure Devops) Publish HTML Results](https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/protractor-end-to-end-tests-configure-on-ci-cd-tfs-vsts-azure-devops-publish-html-results-9143846f579f), you can check it for some more details.

For the dependencies, you could use Yarn or Azure Artifacts/TFS to download packages from the public npm registry, which is a type of private npm registry that you specify in the .npmrc file:

Check the document [Dependency management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops#dependency-management) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm able to call conf.js now but It didn't recognized the webdriver-manager, so I added as an argument and now it just updates the webdriver-manager but doesn't execute my conf.js file